# Python3 "freezes" after inserting unicode characters to sqlite database

Tags: python-3.x, unicode, sqlite, firefox-addon, firefox-addon-webextensions

I am writing a Firefox extension that is connecting to a python3 program through native messaging. Currently I am testing the addon via temporarily loading on the about:debugging page.

The python part is responsible for storing data (eg: information gathered from the web) in an sqlite database. Everything works fine as long as the data only contains characters from the ASCII range. As soon as the data contains a character out of that range (eg: cyrillic), the python program seems to "freeze". At this point if I open the databases in an sqlite browser, the row with the unicode character is not available. Then if I reload my addon at about:debugging (effectively terminating the python program) the rows appear correctly in the database.

I am using parameter substitution for the queries and they are inside `try` blocks so that I can hopefully log any errors but nothing shows up in the logfile (or in the Firefox Browser Console -where output from `stderr` of the native app should show up).

The other strange thing is that anything I try to log within the function where I am inserting data to the db also does not show up in the logfile until the python program is terminated.

What could cause this "freezing"? How could I debug this further?

**Update**

Here is a minimal code with which I can reproduce the problem:

Here is [the native python 3 app](https://pastebin.com/e5s5C19y), and here is the addon [main.js](https://pastebin.com/863EWr9Q) file. Python version is 3.4.3, OS is Ubuntu 14.04 64bit, Firefox is 59.0b11 (64 bit) Developer edition.

The first three messages cause no problem, and when sending the last one the above symptoms are produced.

Comment: Can you show us the code?

Comment: What part of it would be relevant? It's not available on any public platform, and I'd rather not publish it at this stage, but I certainly could post snippets of interest.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that I have not been properly decoding the message from stdin. Originally I had:

```py
raw_message = sys.stdin.read(message_length)
```

And now I have this:

```py
raw_message = sys.stdin.buffer.read(message_length).decode(sys.stdin.encoding)
```

Or this, if stdin's encoding is not 'utf8' (eg: on windows):

```py
raw_message = sys.stdin.buffer.read(message_length).decode('utf8')
```

And this way the freezing does not occur.